# Is there anything to do about a user who reregisters, won't upvote or accept, and asks questions in your specialist area?

Tags: discussion, voting

There is a user on StackOverflow called Frank Computer or Frank Developer, currently with 6 user IDs:

- [User 257279](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257279)
- [User 308999](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308999)
- [User 365570](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365570)
- [User 365845](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365845)
- [User 366636](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366636)
- [User 366797](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366797)

He persistently asks questions in the '[informix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/informix)' area, which is one of my areas of professional expertise.  I don't want to leave such questions unanswered, but since he never accepts any answer, nor gives any upvote, it is singularly unrewarding dealing with him.

**Is there anything that can be done to persuade him to change his ways?**

I don't expect to get large amounts of rep out of this - the subject area is a minority interest area.  But - especially when others answer his questions - I would like him to give some recognition that others have helped.

I suspect this is a lost cause and I'll just continue as now, ensuring that there is a decent answer to any of his questions and upvoting anyone else who does bother to answer.  But it is irksome, to say the least, that he asks questions but won't participate in the community to the extent of giving that which costs him nothing (indeed, that which gives him rep too - but since he doesn't care about that, it doesn't give him an incentive, it seems).

---

[...later...]

There are distinct signs of improvement.  I don't know if someone contacted him; I suspect so (the timing is a little too much of a coincidence).  If so, thank you.  It seems to have had the desired effect.

PS: It was a bit hard to choose 'an answer' - and a rather arbitrary choice.

Comment: He's probably thinking "why do i have to create a new account each time i want to ask a question??"

Comment: Bigger problem for this user is repeatedly duplicating his own questions when he's not happy with the answers.

Comment: I can see the frustration. Its already unfortunate that rare knowledge is often unrewarded, which makes missed opportunities to get something out of sharing it doubly frustrating.

Comment: Sorry for all the grief I caused in those days. I was fairly new to SE and I'm definitely not a sophisticated developer. However, I'm learning more things as I go along and try to answer some questions and upvote/downvote if I feel I know something about the topic being discussed.

Comment: .. However, on the International Informix Users Group (iiug.org) Board, members ask and respond to questions without worrying about whether someone else is going to up/down vote your Q&A. We just say "Thank You" and go on about our way without being obsessed or worried about points, votes, migrations, closings, etc. etc. because "Is it not really only supposed to all be about Q&A's and Discussions?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I merged all the accounts, at least.

In general if this user is not learning and keeps asking low-quality questions with no interaction, I support a suspension or IP ban.

Comment: Well the key here is giving a fair warning.

Comment: I'm not specifically playing the devils advocate here but if they are adding questions and the questions are being answered isn't this what is wanted?  I understand that this user isn't being the best community citizen but they are generating valid questions and Jonathan is working hard to answer them (thanks Jonathan!).  I didn't think the questions looked terrible although I know nothing about informix.  I know this situation sucks for Jonathan but isn't SO the place to go to get answers for questions and this is what is happening.

Comment: @brainimus: He's generating excessive noise, that Johnathan and others have to deal with.  You're not seeing the many deleted duplicate questions, or the deleted personal attack "answers".

Comment: @Michael I understand.  Since I can't see all that noise I didn't realize the issue was that large.

Comment: My attacks, when I first started interacting in SO were in response of being offensively attacked first, they drew first blood!.. Examine the deleted comments for yourselves. Not every one is as knowledgeable as most users in SE. This applies in all other walks of life. Everyone shines in something where others don't, so I've learned to be tolerant and try to help people without expecting anything in return, except RESPECT and maybe that my help will help them become smarter and a better human being!

Comment: I'm just asking, however would it not a privacy laws violation to allow moderator to see someone's ip?

Answer (score 1):

10K users can see [one of his deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563358/begin-viewing-query-results-before-query-ends/2564078#2564078) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563358/begin-viewing-query-results-before-query-ends) that ***he*** asked, where he personally attacked another user. It was not him that deleted / removed it, either.

Its great that you are supporting the tag, just try to think of it that way. Several people have called this person into question. While he seems a bit calmer than some months ago, he's simply not interested in doing anything other than asking (or occasionally answering) questions.

Comment: Yes - things are quieter now than before, so it is less painful.  But not yet much more rewarding. :)