# How do you get the Tumbleweed badge?

Tags: support, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I'm just so confused.

Comment: Check out all the `Related` questions in the right sidebar - they give you an idea of the actual requirements.

Comment: Aside to @John: belated welcome to Meta!  Since you have >200 rep on SO, you can disassociate and reassociate your MSO account with it and get a one-time +100 bonus here.

Comment: honestly this would have been funnier if it had received no answers or up-votes whatsoever.

Comment: Yeah, c'mon people. Show, not tell.

Answer (score 1):

You get it by asking a question that gets no answers, no votes, no comments, and low views for a week.

In other words, you get it as a consolation prize for asking a bad question.

Comment: ha ha at your second sentence

Comment: This amuses me.  You win one (1) `Made Adam Laugh` badge.  Can be traded in for a free unicorn ride at fine unicorn petting zoos everywhere.

Comment: In all seriousness: how low would 'low views' be?

Comment: Not always a BAD question, sometimes just a question that nobody feels like answering or knows how to answer :)

Comment: @BoltClock [Around 10-15](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32376/tumbleweed-how-many-views-is-low). From experience, 17 is too many.

Comment: @BoltClock http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32376/tumbleweed-how-many-views-is-low

Comment: @tim Post It's highly improbable that a developer asking a question on Stack Overflow is the only one able to ask (or answer) a particular question.

Comment: @George - hence the 'nobody feels like answering' :) Some questions, however coherent .. require a time investment that qualified people simply can't afford at the moment. I've run into dozens of them in the C / Linux tags especially when it comes to device drivers. I don't write them down to rush home and answer them, and rarely do I favorite something .. too much noise when I do.

Comment: @George - if it weren't for Jonathan Leffler and a few others, every single `informix` question would earn this badge. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53637/is-there-anything-to-do-about-a-user-who-reregisters-wont-upvote-or-accept-and

Comment: I don't think the question I got my Tumbleweed for was a bad question, but it sure was obscure.  Eventually, I figured it out and answered it myself.

Comment: @BoltClock, @Grace Note: I got it with about 25 views for a question on SuperUser.

Comment: @zneak: I'm guessing the threshold is higher there because Super User has less traffic than Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I wouldn't call a Tumbleweed necessarily a bad question.  Asking a good but obscure question will very likely get one.  It's a consolation prize that you get instead of anything useful, like an answer.

Comment: If i get 1 up vote and 1 down vote, can i get this badge?

Comment: @eirenaios Yes, or indeed 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes, etc.